# Как сделать, чтобы проект был на github, но доступен только по приватной ссылке?

Tags: github

Я хочу сделать свой проект анонимным в github.То есть чтобы он был доступен только по ссылке. Как-то можно это сделать бесплатно?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем ясен ваш вопрос.

если вас  интересует  именно гитрепозиторий, то никак. Нужно создавать аккаунт и платить абонплату 7 долларов в месяц. Есть аналог - bitbucket.org. Там можно создавать приватные репозитории бесплатно.

Приватные репозитории нельзя показывать по ссылке. Тот кому вы хотите его показать, должен будет дать вам логин, а вы его добавить в репозиторий

Публичные репозитории бесплатно можно создавать. Их могут смотреть все кто знает  вашу ссылку на репозиторий или ссылку на ваш аккаунт (логин) или же просто случайно нашел его в списке. Изменять что либо он не может он может только просмотреть ваш репозиторий.